# ngRoute not working when changing module

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

i am working with ngRoute. currently i am using ng-table plugin and jcs-autovalidation plugin. Therefore my module,

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngTable','jcs-autoValidate']);
```

problem is ngRoute not working with above module. when using like below,

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
```

ngRoute is working well. how i use ngRoute with my plugins

Comment: I dont see anywhere you injected ngRoute

Comment: this is my external controller file.

Comment: post your controller and module code

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngTable','jcs-autoValidate']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use one module for your application, and add all the necessary dependencies to it,

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngTable','jcs-autoValidate']);
```

So that you do not have to declare the module again,

```
app.directive('mydatepicker', function () {
}
```

Comment: Its Working !! Thanks Lot